# How can I get printers icons in c#

Tags: c#, printers

Can anybody tell me how can i get the icon of PrintQueue object (like in explorer) in C#. 
I get the list of all printers with this code :

`LocalPrintServer PrintServer = new LocalPrintServer();
                PrintQueueCollection PrintQueuesOnLocalServer = PrintServer.GetPrintQueues(new[] { EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Local, EnumeratedPrintQueueTypes.Connections });`

Thanks in advance
NeoKript

Comment: what do you exactly mean, the image shown in the OS Gui ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want an operating system icon you should try open shell32.dll ( or try with other dll in system ) as a resource file with Visual Studio, you should find the icons there, **but I don't know if you can use in your application**.
Here a screenshot on opening a dll as a resources:
[image]
and here what you obtain:

[image]

Of course you have to try open the icon one by one to look for the one you need, maybe you want the one called 17 ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but how can i know if PrintQueue is a Fax or a Printer for display the good picture ?

Comment: @NeoKript: There's no way that works with 100% certainty, but it's extremely unlikely that a Fax printer wouldn't have the word "fax" in its name.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247035.aspx
(Visual Studio Image Library collection of icons freely usable in your app).

'The Visual Studio 2010 Image Library contains application images that appear in Microsoft Windows, the Office system, Microsoft Visual Studio, and other Microsoft software. You can use this set of over 1,000 images to create applications that look visually consistent with Microsoft software'.

Comment: The library has moved, it can now be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35825

Answer (score 0):

Most of the system icons are embedded resources in the system dll files.

Try looking in `shell32.dll`.

You can use the list [here](http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/87453-listing-of-shell32dll-icon/) to find the icons that you want to use.